# checkbox input ng-model is not binding to form object

Tags: angularjs

For some reason, `ng-model="episodeValue"` not binding to the form object. It is a child of `<form>`. Any ideas why? I would like to keep this a primitive if possible.

```
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                ng-model="episodeValue"
                ng-required="true"
                ng-change="episodeCheckbox(initialNewGoalForm)"/>
                by the end of episode
              </label>
```

---

```
$scope.episodeCheckbox = function(episodeValue) {
  console.log(episodeValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems without a `name` attribute it will not bind to the form controller.

fix is `name="episodeValue"`

```
              <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="episodeValue"
                  ng-model="episodeValue"
                  ng-required="true"
                  ng-change="episodeCheckbox(initialNewGoalForm)"/>
                by the end of episode
              </label>
```